# Get a variable from a Jquery loaded webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the jquery.load to load a div back into the same page then refresh the div to reflect any changes. This works fine until I need a variable from the page I am loading to use within the javascript. For example, if localStorage.username2 changes the browser should reload. But it is not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var partyid = '<?php echo $_GET["Party_ID"]; ?>';
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

if (localStorage.user2==localStorage.username2){

$('#Submission-2').load('http://example.com/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission');
refresh();
}

});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh() 
{ 
 setTimeout( function() { 
if (localStorage.user2==localStorage.username2)
{
 $('#Submission-2').fadeOut('slow').load('http://example.com/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission').fadeIn('slow'); 
document.getElementById("Submit-answer").innerHTML = localStorage.username2;
refresh();
}
else{
window.location.reload();
}

document.getElementById("Submit-answer").innerHTML = localStorage.username2;
 }, 5000); 
} 
</script>
```

This code works until the username changes and the code does not detect it. So the window.location.reload(); function is never executed.

I also have this code in my Submission div.

```
 <div id="submission">
```

```
localStorage.setItem("user2", "<?php echo $user; ?>");
localStorage.setItem("username2", "<?php echo $party_information[0]->Username; ?>");

</script>
</div>
```

So my issue is how do i get a variable from a page loaded using .load?
I am quite new to this only started a few days ago. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using $_GET["Party_ID"] directly on your page, unescaped, you are vulnerable to cross site scripting. Please escape user input.

Comment: looking into that now. I am approaching the vulnerability testing stage in development. BTW I am using WordPress does that make it harder or easier?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should fire your $('#Submission-2).load(...); refresh(); functions when local storage changes.

```
$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
     $('#Submission-2').load('http://example.com/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission');
    refresh();
});
```

Comment: i'm sorry i am still trying to figure out the language. Which script file would this go into?

Comment: This would go inside your jQuery(document).ready( function($){right here!}) function.

Comment: So i would have a function in a function

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. i am outputing the user variable and it is not changing

Answer (score 0):

you can set an interval that fires periodically to check if the variable has changed or not

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if (localStorage.user2 != localStorage.username2){
       window.location.reload();
    }
}, 5000);
```

This runs every 5 second to check if the variable has changed. Note that it could be pretty taxing

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing for the js. Works!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh() 
{ 
var quitfunction = 0;
 setTimeout( function() { 
$('#Submission-2').fadeOut('slow').load('http://example.com/play-with-friends/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission' , function() {
var username = '<?php echo $party_information[0]->Username; ?>';
if (document.getElementById('total').value!=username)
{
window.location.reload();
}
        });
$('#Submission-2').fadeIn('slow').load('http://example.com/play-with-friends/?Party_ID=' + partyid + ' #Submission' );
{
refresh();
}
 }, 5000); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have one more issue though the loaded page is not executing the Jquery in the div